# Django JWT Auth - filtering response for particular user

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I’m implementing JWT authentication in my Django project and at the moment I’m stuck in a part where I’d like to filter response data by my JWT.

I’d like to get particular data referring to authenticated user in my Django view. How can I get this filtered data?

Here’s example for my Settings view.

Views.py

```
Class SettingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # here I'd like to decode my JWT token 
    # and filter the response data for particular user 
    queryset = Settings.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
```

urls.py

```
# ...
router.register(r'api/settings', SettingsViewSet)
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    # ...
]
```

Serializers.py

```
class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Settings 
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'value', 'description', 'office')
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
],
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
],
```

}

Here’s a curl command which I use to get response from server:

```
curl -H ‘Content-Type: application/json’ http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/settings/ -H ‘Authorization: Bearer <Here goes JWT token for particular user>’
```

In response I get all the settings for all users. I’d like to get data only for the authenticated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently logged in user instance should be automatically added to **request** objects by the library you are using. With that, you can override **get_queryset** method to filter the response by currently logged in user, assuming you have a user field in your Settings model:

```
class SettingsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Settings.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Settings.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```